# Why is object still alive?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

Just doing some practice and was breakpointing through this example. I found that the references of earlier created list members was still alive, why?

The `anotherShoe` and `newShoe` still had values that were assigned to their reference members however as you can see, the real objects was cleared. I know I can assign them null values but aren't they automatically nulled/garbage collected when their reference objects have been `List<T>.Clear()`?

Thank you.

```
 List<Shoe> shoeCloset = new List<Shoe>();
            shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe() { styles = Styles.Sneakers, colour = "Red" });
            shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe() { styles = Styles.Sandals, colour = "Green" });
            shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe() { styles = Styles.Flipflops, colour = "Yellow"});
            shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe() { styles = Styles.Loafers, colour = "Brown" });
            shoeCloset.Add(new Shoe() { styles = Styles.Wingtips, colour = "Blue" });

            //int numberOfShoes = shoeCloset.Count;
            //foreach (Shoe shoe in shoeCloset)
            //{
            //    shoe.styles = Styles.Sneakers;
            //    shoe.colour = "White";
            //}

            shoeCloset.RemoveAt(3);

            Shoe newShoe = shoeCloset[2];
            Shoe anotherShoe = shoeCloset[1];
            anotherShoe.colour = "Grey";
            anotherShoe.colour = "Green";
            if (shoeCloset.Contains(anotherShoe))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Contains another shoe");
            }

            shoeCloset.Clear();
            anotherShoe.ToString(); //<---this still contains values after shoeCloset has been cleared.
            newShoe.ToString();     //<---this still contains values after shoeCloset has been cleared.
```

Comment: `Clear()` does not dispose of objects, it only cuts the reference between your list and the instantiated object. This is normal. You still have some references pointing to the first 2 objects, thus they will not be disposed by the GC.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. List.Clear() just clears the list - removes object from the list. But as long as refernces to object exist Garbage Collector cannot free memory it occupies.

Comment: where are you clearing the contents of `anotherShoe` also what's the purpose of these 2 lines `notherShoe.colour = "Grey";
            anotherShoe.colour = "Green";` have you even used the debugger ...? are you familiar with the word `Null` in regards to assignment

Comment: The closet doesn't actually contain the shoes, it contains tags that direct you to where the find the shoes in the back room.  The shoes are still there, even though you've removed all the tags from the closet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object instances are garbage collected when there is no possible way for any executing code to ever access them again.  Since you're holding onto references to these two objects through two local variables that are still in scope, those objects are accessible, and thus not eligible for garbage collection.

The whole point of garbage collection is for you to not have to worry about it.  You will never, ever (barring a few edge cases like `unsafe` code and weak references), try to access an object and find out that the object you're trying to access has been garbage collected.

Comment: Quick caveat: returning an `IEnumerable` from within a `using` statement (and the query utilizes the `using` variable) can easily result in accessing a disposed object. This is an edge case, but one to be aware of. +1 for the right answer though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Disposal of managed resources is entirely separate from collection of managed objects by the garbage collector.  When you are managing an object yourself you can get it wrong; for those objects that the GC is managing, it won't get it wrong.